# Typescript fails to infer the argument types of function properties through optional-boolean

Tags: typescript, boolean, type-inference, union-types

I'm trying to infer the type for another function property based on the value of a specific optional-boolean property within the union type.

It is difficult to explain in sentences, so please look at the code and comments below:

```
interface SingleCallback<T> {
    func: (arg: T) => T;
    value: T;
    multiple?: false | undefined;
}

interface MultiCallback<T> {
    func: (arg: T[]) => T[];
    value: T[];
    multiple: true;
}

type Callback<T> = SingleCallback<T> | MultiCallback<T>;

const mult: Callback<number> = {
    value: [1, 2, 3],//OK
    func: (arg) => [...arg, 1, 2, 3],//OK. The arg is number[]
    multiple: true
};

const singleOk: Callback<number> = {
    value: 1,//OK
    func: (arg) => arg + 1,//OK. The arg is number
    multiple: false
};

const singleNotOk: Callback<number> = {
    value: 1,//OK
    func: (arg) => arg + 1,//Not OK. I want to make arg be inferred as a number, but it is not.
};
```

This works well if "multiple" is explicitly specified. The problem arises when I don't define a "multiple" value. It still works fine for general properties, but only for the argument of function properties, the type cannot be inferred and an error occurs.

What is the reason for this? Can you give me some ideas for solving this?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? I tried the latest version in the TypeScript Playground and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was using 4.3.0, and this problem seems to have been resolved in version 4.3.5.

Comment: https://catchts.com/callbacks here you can find several examples regarding typing callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Works correctly since TypeScript 4.3.2.